# How to install Thai fonts?

Tags: fonts, babel

I am using MiKTeX 2.9, WinEdt 5.5 and Windows 7. What is the easiest way to install the Thai fonts so that I can use the package `thai babel`?

The error message that I got is:

> No file `LTHnorasi.fd` LaTeX Error: This NFSS system isn't set up
>   properly.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please show us a complete document (as minimal as possible) which results in this error. Do you have this font installed on your system? If you don't, you should read a bit on how to obtain and install a new font on Windows.

Comment: I had the tex files in the computer that used Window XP. They works fine. I got the new computer with Windows 7. Trying to set up, the English works but not Thai.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, any OpenType fonts in your system are valid to use in XeLaTeX.
You may not need to install a new Thai font.
Moreover, you may have fonts like `TH Sarabun New` or `Cordia` installed in your font's folder already. 
In case that additional Thai fonts are required, you just simply right click at the `you_new_font.ttf` and then choose `Install`.

In order to use Thai font in your tex, you may use the following lines:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=1.23}
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale “th_TH”
\setmainfont{TH Sarabun New}

\begin{document}
แอลจีเรียบอร์เนียวฮานอยโปรตุเกสมัทราส ปากีสถานอันดามันคอโมโรส อิรัก 
ญี่ปุ่นอุรุกวัยโกลกาตาเอดินบะระ ไลบีเรีย วินเซนต์ซิมบับเวโมนาโคปาเลา 
\end{document}
```

Save it with unicode encoding (UTF-8), then render the document with the command `xelatex thedocname.tex`.
Please make sure that your editor is unicode supported.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the `thaifonts-arundina` you'll have to install. However, note that if you have a Thai keyboard, you might consider upgrading to WinEdt 9, which is unicode-capable, and compile with `XeLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX`, entering Thai text directly and using any Open type font that comprises the Thai alphabet.